# I need to know how to make pie chart in RStudio shiny/ shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, pie-chart, shinydashboard

Here's my data where:

x<-file$Area  #The cities

y<-file$CountOfProvince  #value that corresponds the population of the Area

I dont know how to code these stuff in UI.r and Server.r

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/vignettes/Visual_Guide.html

If you need to learn `shiny` first, then do it: a first Hello World app is ready in 5 Minutes or less: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/